# Indy 10.6.2 idFTP in Delphi 7 - problem with native symbols in filenames while receiving files - probably bad behavior of DefStringEncoding

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy10

I'm using Indy 10.6.2 together with Delphi 7 and Windows 10 64-bit with Polish language.

I run an FTP server: `FTPServer: TIdFTPServer`, and by using `FTPClient: TIdFTP` I am trying to get a file containing national symbols within its file name. Unfortunately, after calling the `Get()` function, on the server side in the `OnRetrieveFile` event, instead of national symbols in `AFileName` I end up with question marks, and this obviously leads to other exceptions.

For tests, I run both: server and client on the same machine and in the same application to eliminate any other disturbances.

On the client side, I already tried:

```
 FTPClient.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
 FTPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
 FTPClient.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding   := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
```

On the server side, I tried:

```
 ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
 ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding   := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
```

None of them makes any difference. I also tried other encodings, but also failed.

Below is my test application, together with text DFM values of client and server.

```
unit Glowny_FTP;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdFTP, ZLibCompression, IdGlobal,
  IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerStream, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdCmdTCPServer, IdFTPServer, IdContext,
  IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    FTPClient: TIdFTP;
    FTPServer: TIdFTPServer;
    IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
      const AUsername, APassword: String; var AAuthenticated: Boolean);
    procedure FTPServerRetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
      const AFileName: WideString; var VStream: TStream);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

begin

  FTPServer.DefaultPort    := 1350;
  FTPServer.Active         := True;

  FTPClient.Host     := '127.0.0.1';
  FTPClient.Port     := 1350;
  FTPClient.Username := 'new';
  FTPClient.Password := 'pass';
  FTPClient.Connect;
  // FTPClient.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  // FTPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  // FTPClient.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding   := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;

  FTPClient.Get('sample ąęśćłó','C:\węzły.cpy',True,False);   // <-- filename containing national symbols
  FTPClient.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AUsername, APassword: String; var AAuthenticated: Boolean);
begin
  if (APassword='pass') then
    begin
      AAuthenticated := True;
    end else AAuthenticated := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerRetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AFileName: WideString; var VStream: TStream);
begin
 // ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
 // ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding   := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  VStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName+'.serv',fmOpenRead); //<-- here I get: "/sample ??????" without UTF8 and "/sample ????" with UTF8
end;

end.
```

and maybe interesting DFM part:

```
object FTPClient: TIdFTP
    Passive = True
    ConnectTimeout = 0
    DataPort = 20
    Password = 'TaJnEH1aS2loD3oSt4ePu'
    TransferType = ftBinary
    NATKeepAlive.UseKeepAlive = False
    NATKeepAlive.IdleTimeMS = 0
    NATKeepAlive.IntervalMS = 0
    ProxySettings.ProxyType = fpcmNone
    ProxySettings.Port = 0
    Left = 104
    Top = 72
  end
  object FTPServer: TIdFTPServer
    Bindings = <>
    DefaultPort = 1350
    TerminateWaitTime = 100
    CommandHandlers = <>
    ExceptionReply.Code = '500'
    ExceptionReply.Text.Strings = (
      'Unknown Internal Error')
    Greeting.Code = '220'
    Greeting.Text.Strings = (
      'Indy FTP Server ready.')
    MaxConnectionReply.Code = '300'
    MaxConnectionReply.Text.Strings = (
      'Too many connections. Try again later.')
    ReplyTexts = <>
    ReplyUnknownCommand.Code = '500'
    ReplyUnknownCommand.Text.Strings = (
      'Unknown Command')
    PathProcessing = ftppUnix
    AnonymousAccounts.Strings = (
      'anonymous'
      'ftp'
      'guest')
    OnUserLogin = FTPServerUserLogin
    OnRetrieveFile = FTPServerRetrieveFile
    SITECommands = <>
    MLSDFacts = []
    ReplyUnknownSITCommand.Code = '500'
    ReplyUnknownSITCommand.Text.Strings = (
      'Invalid SITE command.')
    Left = 104
    Top = 8
  end
```

---

Update:

After Remy's help still no efect. After UTF8Encode() inside FTPClient.Get() I got more question marks on server side. Now my code looks like this:
(I check AFileName on Form1.Caption just for quick debug)

```
...
FTPClient.Connect;

FTPClient.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
FTPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
FTPClient.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding   := IndyTextEncoding_8Bit;

FTPClient.Get(UTF8Encode('sample ąęśćłó'),'C:\węzły.cpy',True,False);
FTPClient.Disconnect;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerRetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AFileName: WideString; var VStream: TStream);
begin
  Form1.Caption := AFileName;
  VStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\tymczas z węzłami obl.aqr',fmOpenRead);
  //  VStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName+'.serv',fmOpenRead);

end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding   := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
end;
```

Comment: DON'T set `DefStringEncoding` manually at all for either `TIdFTP` or `TIdFTPServer`, it is set internally for you. `TIdFTP` uses `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` if the server supports UTF-8 (make sure `TIdFTP.AutoIssueFEAT` is True), otherwise it uses `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit` instead (and you will have to decode non-ASCII strings manually as needed). `TIdFTPServer` uses `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit` unless the client requests UTF-8, then it uses `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8`.

Comment: Do note that since you are using Delphi 7, I would suggest setting `DefAnsiEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_8bit` as well (it is set to `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` by default) and then set it to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` if UTF-8 is enabled successfully.  And yes, I'm aware that this is not entirely conformant with how RFC 2640 says UTF-8 should be used.  There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/22) for that.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I've allready been there. Tried almost all combination of IndyTextEncoding_* both for DefStringEncoding and DefAnsiEncoding for client and for server. Still ???? instead of proper chars. Maybe I just didin't check some crucial checker or my code is invalid and I should write it some other way. Anyway, thank you very much for help.

Comment: When calling `FTPClient.Get()`, you have set `TIdFTP.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` but the `AnsiString` you are passing in for the remote file is not actually encoded in UTF-8. Try using `UTF8Encode()` for that, eg: `FTPClient.Get(UTF8Encode('sample ąęśćłó'), 'C:\węzły.cpy', ...);` Otherwise, the `DefAnsiEncoding` should be left at its default of `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` instead, since your Windows locale is set to Polish

Comment: Also, in the server, setting the IOHandler's `DefStringEncoding` and `DefAnsiEncoding` in the `OnRetrieveFile` event is too late, since the filename has already been read from the socket and decoded to a `string` before the event is fired. You would need to set them (if at all) in the `OnConnect` event instead.

Comment: On a side note: `TIdFTPServer` is a multi-threaded component, but `Form1.Caption := AFileName;` is not thread-safe. You must synchronize with the main UI thread, such as with `TThread.Synchronize()`, when touching UI elements from a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

### Background

The IOHandler's `DefStringEncoding` needs to be set to the byte encoding that you want to use when transmitting strings over the socket.  Indy will send out a Unicode string by encoding it to bytes using `DefStringEncoding`.  And conversely, Indy will read in a Unicode string by decoding the received bytes to Unicode using `DefStringEncoding`.

In Delphi 2007 and earlier, there is an extra step involved. The IOHandler's `DefAnsiEncoding` needs to be set to the encoding that you want to use with `AnsiString`s.  Indy will send out an `AnsiString` by first decoding it from ANSI to Unicode using `DefAnsiEncoding` and then sending that Unicode using `DefStringEncoding`.  Conversely, Indy will read in an `AnsiString` by first reading in a Unicode string using `DefStringEncoding` and then encoding that Unicode to ANSI using `DefAnsiEncoding`.

By default, `DefStringEncoding` is `IndyTextEncoding_ASCII` (for historical reasons), and `DefAnsiEncoding` is `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault`.

### On the client side

`TIdFTP` will automatically switch the IOHandler's `DefStringEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` if it determines that the server supports UTF-8.  Without UTF-8 extensions, the FTP protocol requires the use of ASCII instead.  So, you really shouldn't be messing with the client's `DefStringEncoding` at all.

You were originally passing in the remote filename as a Polish-encoded `AnsiString`, so having `DefAnsiEncoding` set to `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` makes sense on an OS set to a Polish locale.  With `DefStringEncoding` set to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8`, proper UTF-8 should be transmitted to the server.

You later changed the client to pass in a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` instead, but you set `DefAnsiEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit`, so the `AnsiString` does not get converted to Unicode correctly, and thus the subsequent conversion to UTF-8 is malformed.  `DefAnsiEncoding` needs to be set to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` in that situation.  I would suggest leaving the `DefAnsiEncoding` set to `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` and use OS locale encoded `AnsiString`s, unless you have a compelling reason not to.

### On the server side

`TIdFTPServer` will automatically switch an IOHandler's `DefStringEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` only if the client issues an `OPTS UTF-8 <NLST>` or `OPTS UTF8 ON` command (which `TIdFTP` does, but other clients might not).  Note that this is NOT in accordance with [RFC 2640](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2640), which Indy does not fully implement yet.

You are setting both `DefStringEncoding` and `DefAnsiEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8`, which is typically OK, for the most part.  You will end up with UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString`s in events that expose access to `AnsiString`s.

However, the `OnRetrieveFile` event uses `WideString` for its `AFileName` parameter in your version of Delphi. After the server has read in the filename from the socket as an `AnsiString`, it gets passed *as-is* to the event handler, converting it to `WideString` using the RTL's own conversion logic, which uses the OS's locale by default.  So, in your situation, where the `AnsiString` is UTF-8 encoded but the OS locale is Polish, you will end up with a malformed conversion.  Fortunately, you can mitigate that issue by calling the RTL's [`SetMultiByteConversionCodePage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetMultiByteConversionCodePage) function beforehand to perform `AnsiString`<->`WideString` conversions using codepage 65001 (UTF-8) instead.

However, several of `TIdFTPServer`'s events use `WideString` parameters in Delphi 2007 and earlier, and thus there are quite a few areas of `TIdFTPServer`'s internals that rely on the RTL's default `AnsiString`<->`WideString` conversions.  So, I would suggest leaving `DefAnsiEncoding` set to `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` on the server side as well, unless you have a compelling reason not to.  If you want to force `DefStringEncoding` to `IndyTextEncoding_UTF8` regardless of `OPTS` commands, that is OK (provided your clients only ever send UTF-8 encoded paths).

---

With that said, try this:

```pascal
unit Glowny_FTP;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdFTP, ZLibCompression, IdGlobal,
  IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerStream, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdCmdTCPServer, IdFTPServer, IdContext,
  IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    FTPClient: TIdFTP;
    FTPServer: TIdFTPServer;
    IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FTPServerConnect(ASender: TIdContext);
    procedure FTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
      const AUsername, APassword: String; var AAuthenticated: Boolean);
    procedure FTPServerRetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
      const AFileName: WideString; var VStream: TStream);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTPServer.DefaultPort    := 1350;
  FTPServer.Active         := True;

  FTPClient.Host     := '127.0.0.1';
  FTPClient.Port     := 1350;
  FTPClient.Username := 'new';
  FTPClient.Password := 'pass';
  FTPClient.Connect;
  try
    // FTPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    // FTPClient.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault;
    FTPClient.Get('sample ąęśćłó', 'C:\węzły.cpy', True, False);

    { or:
    //FTPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    FTPClient.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    FTPClient.Get(UTF8Encode('sample ąęśćłó'), 'C:\węzły.cpy', True, False);
    }
  finally
    FTPClient.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerConnect(ASender: TIdContext);
begin
  ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  //ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault;
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AUsername, APassword: String; var AAuthenticated: Boolean);
begin
  AAuthenticated := (AUsername = 'new') and (APassword = 'pass');
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerRetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AFileName: WideString; var VStream: TStream);
begin
  VStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName + '.serv', fmOpenRead);
end;

end.
```

Or this:

```pascal
unit Glowny_FTP;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdFTP, ZLibCompression, IdGlobal,
  IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerStream, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
  IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdCmdTCPServer, IdFTPServer, IdContext,
  IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    FTPClient: TIdFTP;
    FTPServer: TIdFTPServer;
    IdAntiFreeze1: TIdAntiFreeze;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FTPServerConnect(ASender: TIdContext);
    procedure FTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
      const AUsername, APassword: String; var AAuthenticated: Boolean);
    procedure FTPServerRetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
      const AFileName: WideString; var VStream: TStream);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetMultiByteConversionCodePage(CP_UTF8);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTPServer.DefaultPort    := 1350;
  FTPServer.Active         := True;

  FTPClient.Host     := '127.0.0.1';
  FTPClient.Port     := 1350;
  FTPClient.Username := 'new';
  FTPClient.Password := 'pass';
  FTPClient.Connect;
  try
    // FTPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    // FTPClient.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault;
    FTPClient.Get('sample ąęśćłó', 'C:\węzły.cpy', True, False);

    { or:
    //FTPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    FTPClient.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
    FTPClient.Get(UTF8Encode('sample ąęśćłó'), 'C:\węzły.cpy', True, False);
    }
  finally
    FTPClient.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerConnect(ASender: TIdContext);
begin
  ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  ASender.Connection.IOHandler.DefAnsiEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AUsername, APassword: String; var AAuthenticated: Boolean);
begin
  AAuthenticated := (AUsername = 'new') and (APassword = 'pass');
end;

procedure TForm1.FTPServerRetrieveFile(ASender: TIdFTPServerContext;
  const AFileName: WideString; var VStream: TStream);
begin
  VStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName + '.serv', fmOpenRead);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you for this deep explanation, but still... it's not working with Delphi 7.

Comment: I've allready tried what you suggested in first part except assigning encoding in FTPServerConnect. I did it this time without expected result. Second solution is not suitable for me because SetMultibyteConversionCodePage is not available in Delphi 7. Looks like in theory it should work but in reality it is not. Well... D7 is a dinosaur. I am aware that you may not be able to test your solutions in such old environment but if you want I can share you my desktop to test those solutions with my locale settings.

Comment: I don't have D7 to test with. `SetMultiByteConversionCodePage()` exists in D2006. D7 may have a global `UserDefaultCodePage` variable you can set. AFAIK, this code *should* work, but I can't *guarantee* it. I suggest you use the debugger to step into Indy's code to see where the data loss is occurring. Is it on the client side when transmitting the UTF-8? Is it on the server side when receiving the UTF-8? Or is it where the server is calling the `OnReceiveFile` event? My gut really thinks it is that last one, because the IOHandler's TextEncoding logic is fairly well tested.

Comment: Looks like data loss is on the server side inside `TIdASCIIEncoding.GetBytes()` where I landed no matter what TextEncoding I chose. Probably the reason why I end up with ASCII is somewhere else but I am too small for such deep investigation. Found ugly way around and that must suit me - described it in answer below. One more time, thank you Remy for help and patience.

Comment: @aa ASCII is Indy's default text encoding (you can change that at runtime by setting the global `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit), but nothing in the code shown should be using ASCII for anything, especially `GetBytes()` which is used when transmitting strings, not when receiving them. Since you were able to track down `TIdACSIIEncoding` being called into, you should be able to follow up the call stack to see exactly where it is being used from.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I gave up with messy TextEncoding under D7. Lost three days and I'm in the same place.

Long investigation led me to `TIdASCIIEncoding.GetBytes()` no matter what encoding type I choose. Here any Char higher than $007F (127) is turned into "?" which is obvious for ASCII but not for UTF8 and ANSI.

I will use longer road around the problem that should work as long as I will communicate just between my two applications. I know it is patching but at least works.

"Solution" :

Inside `FTPClient.Get()`, instead of source string containing national symbols I put string encoded by `IdEncoderMIME.EncodeString()` and on server side inside `FTPServerRetrieveFile()` I delete first char "/" then my string is decoded by `IdDecoderMIME.DecodeString()` and finally I get proper filename on the other side.

Client side:

```
S := IdEncoderMIME1.EncodeString('sample ąęśćłó',IndyTextEncoding_UTF8,IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
FTPClient.Get(S,'C:\węzły.cpy',True,False);
```

Server side:

```
S := Copy(AFileName,2,Length(AFileName));
S := IdDecoderMIME1.DecodeString(S,IndyTextEncoding_UTF8,IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

Ugly but works...

Comment: This is a VERY ugly workaround. And I probably would have opted to use UTF-7 or other similar ASCII-compatible text encoding rather than using Base64.